# How to update gcloud on Google Cloud Composer worker nodes?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, airflow, gcloud, google-cloud-composer

There's a similar question here but from 2018 were the solution requires changing the base image for the workers. Another suggestion is to ssh into each node and apt-get install there. This doesn't seem useful because when auto scale spawns new nodes, you'd need to do it again and again.

Anyway, is there a reasonable way to upgrade the base gcloud in late 2020?

Comment: What's wrong with changing the base image? Can you provide any details what image are you using and what's the similar question?

Comment: What's wrong with messing with the base image is that then I'd have to create and manage that image, which is the opposite of what using a managed service offers.

Comment: So you mean modifying (the existing one) instead of changing (for a different image). There's no newer version of the image fitting your needs?

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko Composer supports its own image versions, which automatically manges the images within an environment's Kubernetes cluster. Changing the images manually for services within those clusters is considered "out of warranty" and generally not recommended.

Comment: Thanks for the response. That's what I assumed would be the case for a managed service on GCP, and hence why I was leaning against going that route.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because task instances run in a shared execution environment, it is generally not recommended to use the gcloud CLI within Composer Airflow tasks, when possible, to avoid state or version conflicts. For example, if you have multiple users using the same Cloud Composer environment, and either of them changes the active credentials used by gcloud, then they can unknowingly break the other's workflows.

Instead, consider using the Cloud SDK Python libraries to do what you need to do programmatically, or use the [`airflow.providers.google.cloud`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/tree/master/airflow/providers/google/cloud) operators, which may already have what you need.

If you *really* need to use the gcloud CLI and don't share the environment, then you can use a `BashOperator` with a install/upgrade script to create a prerequisite for any tasks that need to use the CLI. Alternatively, you can build a custom Docker image with gcloud installed, and use `GKEPodOperator` or `KubernetesPodOperator` to run a Kubernetes pod to run the CLI command. That would be slower, but more reliable than verifying dependencies each time.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I already make extensive use of the Python SDK for many GCP services. Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be an SDK for Google Cloud Run yet. Concretely, what I'm wanting to do from Composer is to update a Cloud Run revision to add a custom tag to it (so I can access the revision without driving traffic to it). The version of gcloud in `1.10.6-composer` is `Google Cloud SDK 300.0.0, beta 2020.07.06, core 2020.07.06` where that feature is apparently not available.

Comment: What I've gone with until there's a more natural alternative: I do as you suggest and run the bash command to upgrade gcloud as a task in my DAG. Not particularly proud of that, but it's getting the job done. I've considered having that part of my DAG trigger a Google Cloud Build build, but would be cleaner in our case to stay 100% in Composer.